# How to find if Notification.Builder tone has stopped playing

Tags: java, android

All,

I am notifying user with Notification.Builder setSound(sound) and want to be notified when the sound has stopped playing. 
I can think of two ways:
1) Register a listener for Builder and get notified.
2) See the mediaplayer if still playing and then decide.

Since I am not sure how the setSound function is implemented in Notification class, can you please advice. 
Thank you.